# PHP Regular Expression Help

Tags: php, mysql, regex

A client has ~7,000 products with a "Your Price: $..." in the description, the price is typed in (there is no existing wildcard).

Here is an example of a description:

`<table cellpadding="5" border="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td><strong>Part #: </strong></td><td>FIV000-2100</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Retail Price: </strong></td><td>$26.39</td></tr><tr><td class="price"><strong>Your Price: </strong></td><td class="price">$23.75</td></tr><tr><td align="center" colspan="2"/></tr></tbody></table>`

Is there a regular expression to use to just remove the Your Price row? What is we wanted to remove the Retail Price row as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (provided `$str` is the html string):

```
$pattern = "/<tr><td class=\"price\"><strong>Your Price: <\/strong><\/td><td class=\"price\">\\$[0-9.]+<\/td><\/tr>/";
$str = preg_replace($pattern, "", $str);
```

The empty string will replace it with nothing, thus removing it.

EDIT:

Escaped some stuff to make it work. I also urge you to use a HTML parser. Let's call this the quick and dirty method.

Comment: +1 This one will work quite effectively if all the records are formatted the same, but you do need to escape the `$` and all the `/` chars in the pattern. (or better yet, choose a different regex delimiter). You should probably add a comma to the char class (in case of `$1,234.56`)

Comment: You have an unescaped forward slash on your first `</td>` there.

Comment: @Justin E. Morgan Thanks! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

[I strongly recommend you use an HTML parser for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). That being said, the following will most likely do what you want:

```
/Your Price:.*?\$(\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

I don't know MySQL regex syntax, so you might want to double-check that.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to parse or modify HTML with regular expressions... Just use something made for it, for example phpQuery: http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/